# issue with decrypting JS file

Tags: javascript, encryption

One of my JS files is encrypted and I can't do anything about it. Someone hacked my host and encrypted my original js file and I don't have a backup for it. Can you guys please help me?

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Here is the file:

```js
O="XvX-X&OO0X$X ength@bX,inharCodeXuX8X X6X,9XhX), .])#XIX(9X#XKXO&X24]XN[OSOerOkX9ORXO*X.X labelO3X7forare.cAt(O#X]X2(v Clasent OX4XZ[Op.push(.jo (OmX/O/Xal'9X>[eturn .mp3OXlX1}}}tebl kO]ii@lrX}5],_$O9OonYtypXDr.splitangeX87X3layOT@kOe>.@pacity boXB;if(imgse to you^9XS95<-tag ui-penX0a=0;a<cuXRXs2X’s tr gO=Xre«.l;a+ic—-O1xODO^loadack.O,k=b,b+98X¦XjŸk/Oe NowwOgOUsubs®(mXJ91X3chO71OnoutXfS®.from25XCO% sv@X=>O'ti&&f„e.½•85]XHXsX-cd be],O>O(OYOOSamObrŠfˆ¤udioullOV X{scro+b+1)gumoffbtnOWoÕll g¼h=94*(;el¤ O`X@ XO){noXm»¼0°plac™(d+.com1E4leÛáXmheOui-OB¶cplulick:XTcOhttp://{ˆign¼O>, OCX;O[@OSYçhXîmidæOYfrX6X,8,OM2E5O:dôamebo¼0O@/óùrdú tro3X^Xhofroyˆ\"X(8]]X.9X-9X7_$_acX1[]](X&}else {nction}}}}}X6X/,X(o@hpen:qX>32XX9X34]]= X+2);],autfXIXFXBaXNXGcb4[X:2){QX8dXPX8moXDX,rXmentif()}LX@X;m,X:25 X296b4~XA2X)doX5b4[ƒn… X632X_$O9(p,~XŠ245„2[90]XK81ˆ8X0[O`a~O)r@k 380’XJ}thisX>1],(window> 1024X04X,tTim[Xgerse¢X.X X?O8XFtEle€var u( 1Ÿ)œ50) typeofalse2XM@bX6ompleteunceIn]]XrX<ŽX+11X/X'152dialogeoutŽtoas])Xin5£7³$(›–X#56ž¦0¥51E3== 27)£5{cO½)¾0Ãb])[X<500eX[6¤:$Oj}durOP:ÄÉ,{Ê)11tru~2E3,eas:Xg3žsËÏ¼gÐ$« ~geX,tepXksMath£ÑÕ$Ö87ˆdiv 2rogress5žr+ 1×4s)X.1¶Me~¬f CC!Á@kÙXi~ndef¼¶-X/“2211{m¼u2çtes:~b4[6¶J0O0ˆ~a$º§œ04°è15,sXL~1žXG60>OF1~s:0,timcondóe=X:19Xf~X_~]]îeôSepaùrator´Æ)6#btn¤ifú:‡10]}".split('\"');Q="evˆ(funcÈ—(àc=[88,79,86,82,60,70,76,89,94,85,81,74,65,66,75,80,87,71,90,72Îg=[Î±+)g[c[a]]=a+1;a=[Îd=0;d<×s.l;d++àl=×s[d]™(~),n=l.l-1;0<=n;n--àh,e=l[nÎf=nÓ,m=0,p=e.l,k,b=0;b<p;b++àh=b)¢k=g[hÜk-1)Ö-32·+Ýif(96==h)Üc.l-32Ö)+b+2)-32·=2Ýc—t ue;nÓ==f&&(f=[;k>mÉ,k));f„l[h+1;m=b+1}nÓ!=f&&(m<pÉ)),l[n]=f…))}a„l[0}g=a…);c=[126,92,96,10,42,39].c—cat(c);d=ÃC(64);(±+)g=gãabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.chAt(a))…ÃC(c[a);rŠgã!)…d)}('O[_$_acb4=[.amOb¶5miOdhoriz—tˆtruÔopÈoOdvˆuÔOBhtmlG¶5disablÔadd€ÚdisabædpropX¶cmiOd°move€sXéÚ st@sfOH¶B¶5cêÐO)¶GO)¶Z¶cm ZésBO)#âÔ  dex@hflvˆ#ÙC—t uÔ‘xt§O<TaggetEæm@tyIdkeyupO_ddEv@mis‘nï#“Úíthemobiæ stˆlä/C@j@iE@jI@l@nNowESSõ89žs@jõ96C@m01žv@n02žvE05žv@s18žp@n19žx@t20srì_ttrO_Ò–°a‘EæmO stt.XWstt‹_uto@vœloopp°@moadvolumÔpœO‚X.XWOX‹‚Z.XWOZ‹‚?.XWO?‹_llœÚwhichhide§ÈmèØžkÏI“OûO>>âe@withO>þcopyrOhO@p>@vowed by @ka h°f¼íclasÿehµä/OYtget¼_blankOY°l¼followO]€ÿehµä@k/pX`ap©dòtoolÚ´o©X|#O1O,xODÔO1Xw–losÔ#O1EOEO,scìbEOEð-closÔO1-eOEXwposiÈoOdfixed–sÚbodyð-bµžkO;Xiui-O;¨widget¨sta‘-default¨corn-ˆl¨O;-ic—-—ly uiX;-bµO˜olXDOfe¼@tµO@O4>ð–hild°n1-eOEO+bžv°pO^fiæsø@v°pOPøIniÈˆiz gøCOAO^toÅøCheck gø@sppliìPÅsø@moad gø°moveXP-´SO-‚<øfadeInOQeXVSO- OQe¿Xb@Ègžvœ vˆid!OQO-¤¿showò²­vˆid!OF>OQtatusO7žvœ authiìP...Xbf ityžst‘mptO^ìAi—...­ìA g¹>¹>¹X`COAed!­ìAed!OF>X/1Om,OM¤tXb@meftö¶þX/3†7†10†11/20Xb@jOhö¶ZX/13†17†20/20žwaitO^ÅøCOAi— EstablishedøSv @jesp—¤ @h@u!ž³pµets ‚Xø.XQ¶5»ž³sucessfÓy!–ompæ‘Xwf itysw g–eilO_nimatÔcounOHeachòXU¶5@³pµets ‚ZòXQO).XUO)@hpÈmizOPøopaqueöXP-OnžkÏI“sOûO>>ï#ifrX}žwaitO^ß!O+!òüO;¤tèno‘þma -O+`wrapInnXPþXx´Xw@ÈgÀsÀXl>@k£XiOn-£@bO(£/´-£.png@b/>OF>OFX1¤XVŒpXXÀÆòma -O+O_p©dTo–l—eþstatusO7Xl>þsO-Œ²Œ¤¿`p°©dOQeXV ¶§žkXiOfeOO‚XO]@xems@k/>žkXiOfeOO‚ZO]@xold@k/>þgen‚X1XQ‚XŒXU‚XÆþO!Ì‚XO@£O(£/OXÌ.pngOYˆt¼OX@b/X`beOiþgen‚Z1XQ‚ZŒXU‚ZÆþO!Ì‚ZO@£O(£/OZÌ.pngOYˆt¼OZ@b/X`.XQXU!¶+òfootþXxÁ1Xx@X=X1Xxb`.¤XV²i‘m¤ti‘mOGpXXXP-bXPOOO?feOOpXXXxbžkpXiüO@/p>C—gratulOPs!º we need to addO^thisXc¥r‚1. @tutÍOi add gXc¥r‚1, æt@fs do 2-s‘pß. CêOa‚?‚;!òüXbXzÐžkO;‚IÙO6@‘OiiOì?O˜oæ¼O;O]O6º!@kO4>@kpX o‘O]No‘: TheXcwillÍ s ¥r‚1 —ce youXzOaß!@k/p>XP-ouOHstylÔdispœ: l eXa»:190pxXaheOh:70pxXamg ëposiÈ—:°laÈveXatopërOhëbottomëæftëo :1XaXY‘Oi, XYsfOHO6 nowÍOi Ème limit runs Á. IfOaß has notÍenXzd with Oa Ème limit provided,OaXcwillÍ canceæd!m‚ObdownÈON#mTiON.ÈON#m@mockTimXn-ÈON@kO;‚IÙO6@sftiOì?O˜oæ¼O;O]O6º!@kO4>XY‘Ô#XOòcx-no‘òcx- putESXYsftX|-fÓß100%fadeToOQhe-O;ÚØ-locksociˆ-lockXn1/1OQ‘p-OGžxood @rob, @joyˆes!º we canXzOa last s‘p.Xn-OfÔChoo¤ —e ofOa Øs andXz it!Xn-no‘òØþpXXÀÆcsheJ-O?OC-OJ-OfeX|/XOXyabÁO,sbÁO_bÁXwOC-widget-ovœuiX;-clo¤X|/abÁXyiXoÚ#ÙIXoÚiXos¡iXoXyO<sO,vœÚO<s¡O<XyfaqO,laqfaq¡faqXyìKÚ#ÙCOKÚìKs¡ìK.htmlò/aÒO4.oggò/aÒO4.mp3gatÔeasy@sÒEffectÚO;fOdvcêoOdM@h@pSED@h@wN–aptu°EvÚ—mou¤dowOd—mou¤up—c—‘xtmenuÑ];Xr$àOiO2z=Â0;ñt=Â17X^1Olz)XsOl{ršt1ÎoriOPXt2Îanima‘Xt3Îm :å,max:5E4,vˆue:å,chškD,EàO[CXj5XJ8XCC)O.åXM13O/‰13‡}O.5E4XM15O/‰15‡ŽXL15ñl”@l+ åXH13ñx”@x- å)}XelO2z=Â19;ñt=Â2ý1Olz)XsOl{ršt1ÎoriOPXt2Îanima‘Xt3Îm :÷,max:1E6,vˆue:÷,chškD,EàO[CXj5XJ20XCC)O.÷XM2Ç‰2ÇX}O.1E6XM22O/‰22‡ŽXL22ñl”@l+ ÷XH21O[I”I- ÷)}Xee(àOt(àO<ID= ¬6X_24Xj25;uXR= •24]+‚<ID¢¬8X_27àuXR= ¬6X_27Xj24}¢$X:0OjXs29]]x3e 6XM3ÇXX>[3Ç'9};Â3ý32]]($X:0Oj)}O[u=dX435X_34;uXs3XS36ÎtXL3ÇX#1ÎtrueXeì2u=Â38;O[t=•39];iX-X&O9404194243944459464794849950519525395455]ŽŽ}};uXs5XS56ÎtXejO2@z=dƒXpX760]XpX761]Xp4[X@z¯E@zÞ@z¯qXp4[XAdO2v=dƒ;v67];v68];vËv¯EvÞv¯q;vXsXAhO2y=dƒ;y69];y70];yËy¯EyÞy¯q;yXsXAfO2w=dƒ;w71];w72];wËw¯EwÞw¯q;wXsXAk()OrdX473]{b;Ñ}}Og(x)OrdX474]]|| dX435]]&& !dX473]OrxXs75]]== 2|| xXs75]]== 3àb;ÑŽ$(w dow)Xs84]]Xrài();l();e(XL77X^7OlXL80X^79X_78XJ8ý82X_81]XH88Â›Ê›{OJ€sXt89Îauto@h©:OL»:350,clo¤@hnEscape:OL°sizXddraggXdmodˆ:true,o©Xkm,nXM92Â›_O$¾Ê93Â›_O$})}}XL91X3{OJ€sXt94Îauto@h©:OL»:350,clo¤@hnEscape:OL°sizXddraggXdmodˆ:true,o©Xkm,nXM¸96XJ99Â¸25¾_O$XJ›Ê93Â¸25¾_O$})},c°a‘XkXM10ý102X_101X^82X_100}}XL31OpO2r=$OqX?[104X_5|| 0;$OqX?O8XF)¢r@k 1 05ª206X*07ª508ª7 09ª806ª910ª1011ª11OkX9Â113[X<ORX 14XG16X^115]](XL118XCO%17ª19 14XG16‡(119ª2020XG21[X<Â123‡'119X5;Â1Ä24ª2126XG23‡(119‡'127ª2928XGÄ29X*030XG23‡(127XGÄ31X*132XG16[X<Â3ý7OlXL133X5;Â135X5O`aX'134X*236X*337X*538XG35‡(134X*639XG41X5O`aX'140X*742X*843ª4044XG4ÇX(140ª4111ª42 45ª4846ª4945ª5047ª51 11ª6048XG49X5}eX[70)Or$(w dow)[Xg0Oj> 1024àd()\"};$Oq¿ê·XG49ÅXf8»Ý‚}‚‚Ç71$Oq¦¥1ê/1ÂXGOpX5}Ç80XuX8X 59ð»5}Ç90)Or$Ÿ)£0Oj h(‚;$Oq¿¶G9O·ðÅXf20»Ýì32X_1‘$aÎâ12X_òm¹200OR‘-n~ãed&& CCÁ_$~10÷14÷[18³‘03‘6y~y¼stalls.com/59òf(áu~¹2E3OR~,@moadO^modul ~]‚Ç~>â6X_‘^8È~ocu€Xs‘s1æ)Îhttps://frida~4[56Œ~outŽÆOR~¢¹À~(›)Xs3~-OJ-titlebar—%12~bññ~$(†§O34ì64Íe;~6ÈXà²X|/‘^7~e=¯O;¯ é3­;~ŒÜ‘Jò‚ï­)–~]ïÍe)–~ööt= †výicOPÎ.O+Ón-O+‘s5ø~7÷0XaÓn-c±ìrch-OòoggO ~Û-On~üO6@~59†lse Orr@k ~62­;~[5]@t–‘h[~Œ~ñ>~!important;Îbo²~ O! ìble:OL~‚O~$(Œ—%5—/cb4~ classOU—#[~:f©—@/Ù—Ymarg¼—Slock¤~nsÍction~;@zO3é5ò(f©—34[~:Œ—*à]i~ bo²—+-~.html#~ c±—U0¯ ÎOJìme@hff¤—_udio/~resources~fu ~ž†$O990~Œò=@t–~1O/~ srcOU~.OZ—0m~pÛÎü@~earch¼g~;CÁ~])–—ktTiìccOb~(O[—=b~/O;ÓmOW~@iýy~-O<~[104~_a~...~button~play¤~–c~iframàvýy—]@k~onnect~slid¤—Sui~en¤at~xamplà@k/Ù~numb¤~t¤~idOU~¸~om€~­,~.item~m¤~-labelìtion—Ss~qO`Î.Î@~=¯~e~sÓms~¯ ~gold~¨Îc~¯>~¼g Îa~[_$_~ thàount~btn-~n~span~titl~idth~ight~forà)~sàÈ~/20~sp¼~}}}}~58])~º~{',‚}‚˜91´ÀíXAÜÌª94ˆÂª61®˜98û2ª64ë63ª6515˜99´ÀÌª67°79ˆ66]˜100û8»*X*X*}}Òj(‚;X:Â 87[90•89]}µ70ë69ª71ßµ7473ˆ72ª76X02ˆ75 3378)œ77ˆ16ª16”0X02ˆ79ª82®µ35”3ª41”4 0Ø86”5ª9Ø89”8ª90°7Èµ9277ˆ91 8X-79ˆ93ª94°7È¨$º§õ5]¨qõ6]í{valuXBchangeX;Ì]‚,c±X;Òf(‚;c()68ª704ˆ69ë97 33®µ98ßµ33ë19Ø99Ú01‹,00Ú034Ô02ª644ˆ63Ú05°79Ô04Ú0X-57Ô06ž‡07Ú17þ01‹,09 33°7È13æøÞ2ÿ‚15æøÞ4ÿ‚17°79Ô16ÚäXJ;X<Þ9ß20®‚,9E5æá¬f uãedCCÁ‡21]load@mock¤(1009return}};äXJ}XKX<Ž0‚¶-84Ô41•æ3‡24žmax@XG‡24]Š83°æ50,026ß294Ô280ÔÂÚ31‹,30Ú33‹,32Ú35‹,34Ú36®38þ26X02Ô37]X<X.},15E3‚X+93„2ä[90 83°æ50,1‚‚,createX;Xæ4077Ô39]‚}43þ42š42¡46•244™42å48þ47š47¡50•249™47å52þ51š51¡54•253™51å56þ55š55¡5X-8È{¸X34[257™55å60þ59š59¡62•261™59“ÒXæ67°26È{ogg:‡63žmp3:‡64ževentType:XA18žplayType:‡65]})$X>268øœ8f©treturn ›œ57øX.¨u=$(›uX>Â0Ô69žtXK;¨b=‡5];‰74ø‰ÂXMEventX>Â1ø‰Â3g‰Â4g;‰Â5k};‰Â5 new @l©‡76]‚)(j@qu¤y)‘!}‘}‘#}‘$}‘%}‘'}~]X+‘*}‘6òXAò}}~X:~‡~8°~(f©~8È†°8~[95ž†X:~Class:b~©m,n)~cu€[~»>~7†ablXB~È{¸~$(XA~:f©~se¢eout‘@:~[XA~rueXL:~:200,open~b4[~e:faXN‘Fàdal:Íe‘Ih~hnEscap~width:ìXNw~close@~[85])~‚‚}~,hidà2~lse,~:fal~ragg~esiz)".split('\"');o=" €‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ".split('');i='';for(U=0;U<2;U++){u=O[U].split('');for(J=u.length-1;J>-1;J--)Q[U]=Q[U].split(o[J]).join(u[J]);i+=Q[U].replace(//g,'"').replace(//g,"\\")}eval(i);
```

Comment: There are 2 kinds of people: those who backup, and those who will...

Comment: Abusive language is going to get your question closed.

Comment: well its a  really furious moment, I don't know why there re people try to  harm other people just for fun this why I'm angry

Comment: You may be angry but this isn't a forum. You're new here, so make sure you look at the edits that have been made to your question to make it more neutral.

Comment: There are 2 kinds of people: those who loose data, and those who don't.

Comment: ok guys what suppose these comments to help in my situation

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing you can do about it unless you know what encryption method was used to encrypt it have the private key to decrypt it.

In the future you should do the following:

- Keep a backup of your source files. Version control systems like Git are ideal for this.
- Keep your servers patched and up to date.
- Use stronger passwords and methods of authentication.
- Never work directly off of your production server.

If the code still runs then there is probably a script decrypting it somewhere. Find it and run it to see how it's decrypting it. You should be able to adjust the decryption script enough to `console.log` the result of the decryption to your browser console.

Comment: but my site still working with this file ? I mean the file still readable

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your original question.